# Parallel algorithm for connected components

Tags: multithreading, algorithm, graph, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I have to find the best algorithm from already known for parallel computing of connected components of graph.

Here is a brief outline of my data and computer architecture:

- I have access to a computational cluster with several thousands of
  processors (memory is not shared, but I expect that there should be
  enough memory in a single node to assess my needs for the whole
  data).
- my graph has rather small ratio of edges number to vertices number (about 5)
- I expect the most of connected components to be very small (2-3 vertices)
- there will be, however, very big components with millions of vertices (constituting even up to 10% of total vertices number).

I have read about parallel algorithms for computing connected components of graphs. As I have noticed, some of them base on the classical BFS approach for the serialized case. To be honest, I got a bit lost in the number of these algorithms. Could anyone give me some advice, which algorithm would be the best for my purposes?

Comment: How big is your graph?

Comment: Tens of millions of nodes, I guess, since 10% is "millions". That's not a huge graph. Do it serially.

Comment: You can design your application in "flow-based concept", see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow-based_programming

Comment: 500 million nodes, 2, 5 billion edges

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Ligra](http://jshun.github.io/ligra/) is either the state of the art or close to it for single-machine multicore implementations. It should be able to handle your graph no problem.

[Connected Components at Scale via Local
Contractions](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1807.10727.pdf), by my colleagues Jakub Łącki, Vahab Mirrokni, and Michał Włodarczyk, is the state of the art (at least, that I know about) for MapReduce algorithms. We've used it on graphs a thousand times bigger than yours.